# PayPal (ExpressCheckoutAPI) Shipping Tax

Tags: paypal

Okay, so I've searched, and asked on the PayPal forum but no one will respond. My problem is as follows. When specifiying the Shipping Cost in the PaymentDetails sent to paypal, PayPal will not accept the Tax on this in the Tax and Order totals.

For example:

```
Item Cost = £1
Item Tax  = £0.20
Shipping Cost = £1
Shipping Tax = £0.20
```

I would send these values:

```
    PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType()
    {
        ItemTotal = ItemCost
        ShippingTotal = ShippingCost,
        TaxTotal = ItemTax + ShippingTax,
        OrderTotal = ItemCost + ShippingCost + ItemTax + ShippingTax,
    };
```

However, PayPal will say the item totals dont match.. This is because it will not accept ShippingTax to be added?

Has anyone got a work around for this? I need to show customers what portion of their shipping is cost, and what the total vat is on the paypal page? Not sending the shipping tax in TaxTotal and OrderTotal gets round the error, but then the tax is not shown or charged!

Getting desperate on this issue... please lend a hand if you use PayPal express checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, PayPal responded and said they do not support this scenario of charging tax on shipping. Very poor for an international payment provider.

I have changed my code to now put through an item of Web Order with the total, and the vat on this.

I will be changing PayPal out for something else better as soon as possible.